# delphi, class, delete

Tags: delphi, классы

{ИСПРАВЛЕНО 03.05, см "!!!" для исправлений}
D 10.
Вот есть классы

```
TMy=class
{public\publicher}
a:integer;
sl:TStringlist;
end;

TMyF=class
{public\publicher} // тут читаю - http://www.delphibasics.ru/Public.php - в1: объясните разницу?
i:integer;
s:string;
My:TMy;
end;

var MyF:TMyF; 
!!!{my:TMy;} {вот это не надо, исправления от 03.05.17}
```

использую

```
..begin
MyF:=TMyF.create;

!!!{my:=MyF.tMy.create;} {это не правильно, исправление от 03.05.17}

MyF.My:=MyF.tMy.create; // Правильно ли создаю и надо ли если основной клаcс уже есть? т.е. без этой строки могу ли уже обращаться к MyF.My.. подклассам A,SL?}
...

MyF.free; // В2. Если я тут класс уничтожаю, в котором TMy родился - память и он сам уничтожится? (или перед этим надо myf.my.free делать?)
end;
```

Comment: Delphi? в 2017?

Comment: @GroZa а в чем проблема? вы и про C/C++ такие комменты пишите?

Comment: А прикиньте многие еще и на 7-ке работают, которая в 2002 вышла примерно. Это вам не windows писанный на ц два креста, который каждую неделю по гигабайту обновляет

Comment: @teran, ну у с++ ниша уже есть и дофига чего на нем написано, а вот на делфи я знаю только что AIMP3 плеер написан :)

Comment: @gil9red не делфях тоже много чего написано, но это больше касается корпоративного сегмента. на сайте эмбаркадеро раньше даже раздел был такой "супер-пупер продукты созданные на делфи" (: основная проблема не такого широкого распространения имхо высокая стоимость IDE и по факту если идти в ногу со временем, то это ежегодная стоимость.

Comment: 03.05. Писал без проверки, большое сорри. Внес изменения. Повлияет ли это на ответы?

Comment: @Gu. нет, на ответы это не повлияет

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TMyF = class
public
  i: integer;
  s: string;
  My: TMy;

  constructor Create(aMy: TMy);    
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TMyF.Create(aMy: TMy);
begin
  inherited Create;
  My := aMy;
end;

destructor TMyF.Destroy;
begin
  My.Free;
  inherited;
end;

MyF := TMyF.Create(TMy.Create);
try
  ...
finally
  MyF.Free;
end;
```

Добавление от @kami:

Предупреждение: предложенная реализация деструктора должна использоваться только в том случае, если создаваемый объект `TMyF` становится владельцем переданного в его конструктор объекта `TMy`.

Comment: Надо бы добавить в ответ предупреждение, что предложенная реализация деструктора должна использоваться только в том случае, если создаваемый объект TMyF становится владельцем переданного в его конструктор объекта TMy. Из текста вопроса это не очевидно.

Answer (score 2):

Тут все зависит от поставленной задачи. TMy можно создать и в самом конструкторе, а не передавать его туда параметром. Тогда он гарантированно будет существовать и в деструкторе не нужно ничего менять.

```
constructor TMyF.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  My := TMy.Create;
end;
```